# Wygwam - IE8 issue - editor doesn't load and throws javascript error

Tags: wygwam

We're having an odd issue with several sites we run on ExpressionEngine for clients using IE8 and 9 in the control panel. I've seen similar problems here on the forum but nothing that fits the bill here exactly (or solves the problem)

When an edit entry screen loads, the WygWam editor starts to load and then disappears leaving an empty space and a javascript error. Screengrab attached. I've managed to replicate the problem in Browserstack, so i'm fairly confident it's not an issue with the end user's machines.

Error is:

'name' is null or not an object
ckeditor.js line 804

Enabling IE compatability mode doesn't seem to help either. It seems to be working ok on one site which is running v 2.3.4.1 but fails on two other sites running 3.1.2

Any ideas on how we might fix this? As having the client ring me and make the changes myself every time is very quickly going to wear thin!

Cheers!

[image: screengrab of error]

Comment: IE8 is an old browser at this point. Why don't they upgrade to a newer browser?

Comment: Thanks Anna, but if that was a possibility we'd already have gone that route. Unfortunately corporate IT departments are rarely willing to upgrade one department of their organisation just because one website they use needs it. :-(

And of course, even if they upgraded to 9, it wouldn't solve the problem.

Comment: I totally understand. It's just ancient.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested an IE8 page load using IE Tester with WYGWAM 3.2.1 installed and there wasn't an error. WYGWAM is at version 3.2.2 as of Nov 13, 2013 so I'd suggest an upgrade as the first step.